# Some commands from PSTricks do not work in MikTeX

Tags: miktex, pstricks

When I try the following in MikTeX, the `\rput` command works, but the `\psline` command doesn't.
I compiled with XeLaTeX.
I've tried adding/removing various packages, an many other things,  but no good.
As far as I know all my packages are up to date.
Thanks for any help.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=0.08in,yunit=.08in}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,15)

\rput[c](-5.8,16) {${H}$}  

\psline{->}(12,16)(16,16)

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

This is my log file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (MiKTeX 23.5) (preloaded format=xelatex 2023.5.8)  8 MAY 2023 14:19 entering extended mode  restricted \write18 enabled.  %&-line parsing enabled.
**./nasAFIN.tex (nasAFIN.tex LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2023-04-20> (C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class (C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size12.clo File: size12.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option) ) \c@part=\count181 \c@section=\count182 \c@subsection=\count183 \c@subsubsection=\count184 \c@paragraph=\count185 \c@subparagraph=\count186 \c@figure=\count187 \c@table=\count188 \abovecaptionskip=\skip48 \belowcaptionskip=\skip49 \bibindent=\dimen140 ) (C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC) \KV@toks@=\toks16 ) (C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC) ) (C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.c fg File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration ) Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 107.

(C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\xetex.def File: xetex.def 2022/09/22 v5.0n Graphics/color driver for xetex )) \Gin@req@height=\dimen141 \Gin@req@width=\dimen142 ) (C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty Package: amsmath 2022/04/08 v2.17n AMS math features \@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option. (C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions \@emptytoks=\toks17 \ex@=\dimen143 )) (C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols \pmbraise@=\dimen144 ) (C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names ) \inf@bad=\count189 LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234. \uproot@=\count190 \leftroot@=\count191 LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line
399. LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410. \classnum@=\count192 \DOTSCASE@=\count193 LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496. LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line
499. LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620. \Mathstrutbox@=\box51 \strutbox@=\box52 LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722. LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723. LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724. LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725. \big@size=\dimen145 LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744. \macc@depth=\count194 LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905. LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910. LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940. LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970. LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971. \c@MaxMatrixCols=\count195 \dotsspace@=\muskip16 \c@parentequation=\count196 \dspbrk@lvl=\count197 \tag@help=\toks18 \row@=\count198 \column@=\count199 \maxfields@=\count266 \andhelp@=\toks19 \eqnshift@=\dimen146 \alignsep@=\dimen147 \tagshift@=\dimen148 \tagwidth@=\dimen149 \totwidth@=\dimen150 \lineht@=\dimen151 \@envbody=\toks20 \multlinegap=\skip51 \multlinetaggap=\skip52 \mathdisplay@stack=\toks21 LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line
2953. LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954. ) (C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support \symAMSa=\mathgroup4 \symAMSb=\mathgroup5 LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold' (Font)         U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106. )) (pstricks.sty Package: pstricks 1997/03/25 package wrapper for PSTricks pstricks.tex  (pstricks.tex `PSTricks' v97 patch 14  <1999/12/23> (tvz) \pst@dima=\dimen152 \pst@dimb=\dimen153 \pst@dimc=\dimen154 \pst@dimd=\dimen155 \pst@dimg=\dimen156 \pst@dimh=\dimen157 \pst@hbox=\box53 \pst@boxg=\box54 \pst@cnta=\count267 \pst@cntb=\count268 \pst@cntc=\count269 \pst@cntd=\count270 \pst@cntg=\count271 \pst@cnth=\count272 \pst@toks=\toks22 (pstricks.con) \psunit=\dimen158 \psxunit=\dimen159 \psyunit=\dimen160 \pslinewidth=\dimen161 \pst@customdefs=\toks23 \pslinearc=\dimen162 \everypsbox=\toks24 \psframesep=\dimen163 \pslabelsep=\dimen164 \theoverlaybox=\box55 )) (C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xet ex.def File: l3backend-xetex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: XeTeX \g__graphics_track_int=\count273 \l__pdf_internal_box=\box56 \g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count274 \g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count275 \g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count276 ) (nasAFIN.aux) \openout1 = `nasAFIN.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line
17. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 17. LaTeX Font Info:  ... okay on input line 17. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 17. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 17. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 17. LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 1
7.

(C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd File: ts1cmr.fd 2022/07/10 v2.5l Standard LaTeX font definitions ) LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 17. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 17. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 17. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17.

(latdefs.tex) \c@thm=\count277 \c@exmp=\count278 \c@fig=\count279 \c@notation=\count280 \c@terminology=\count281 LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 100 .

(C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A ) LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 100 .

(C:\Users\mcsor\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B ) [1

] [2] Overfull \hbox (28.36612pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 259--259 []\TU/lmr/bx/n/17.28 Neighborhood distinct graphs, labelled graphs,  []

[3] Overfull \hbox (35.67044pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 309--316 []\TU/lmtt/m/n/12 (2) For each $\OML/cmm/m/it/12 H[]$ \TU/lmtt/m/n/12 list all  subsets $\OML/cmm/m/it/12 S \OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 ^^R \OML/cmm/m/it/12 V\OT1/cmr/m/n /12 (\OML/cmm/m/it/12 H[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 )$ \TU/lmtt/m/n/12 for which $\OML/cmm /m/it/12 S \OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 6\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 = \OML/cmm/m/it/12 N[]\OT1/cmr/m/n /12 (\OML/cmm/m/it/12 u\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 )$  []


Overfull \hbox (27.70479pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 309--316 \TU/lmtt/m/n/12 for all $\OML/cmm/m/it/12 u \OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 2 \OML/cmm/m/it/12  V\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 (\OML/cmm/m/it/12 H[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 )$\TU/lmtt/m/n/12 , \TU/ lmtt/m/it/12 i.e.\TU/lmtt/m/n/12 , $\OML/cmm/m/it/12 S$ \TU/lmtt/m/n/12 is dist inct from all neighborhoods  []


Overfull \hbox (36.23996pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 329--332 []\TU/lmtt/m/n/12 (4) Remove non ND graphs and then isomorphic copies of the re maining  []


Overfull \hbox (56.9855pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 361--419 [][]  []  []  []  []  []

[4] Overfull \hbox (7.43787pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 465--465 []\TU/lmr/bx/n/17.28 Constructing NAS Graphs from labelled ND  []

[5] Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 526--528

 []


Overfull \hbox (0.59663pt too wide) detected at line 550 \OML/cmm/m/it/12 V\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 (\OML/cmm/m/it/12 G[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 ) = \OMS /cmsy/m/n/12 f\OML/cmm/m/it/12 U[]; U[]; [] ; U[]\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 g [] \OML/cmm /m/it/12 E\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 (\OML/cmm/m/it/12 G[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 ) = \OMS/cmsy/m/ n/12 f\OML/cmm/m/it/12 U[]U[] \OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 j \OML/cmm/m/it/12 G\OT1/cmr/m/n /12 [\OML/cmm/m/it/12 U[] \OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 [ \OML/cmm/m/it/12 U[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/1 2 ] = \OML/cmm/m/it/12 N[] \OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 _ \OML/cmm/m/it/12 N[]\OMS/cmsy/m/n /12 g\OML/cmm/m/it/12 ;  []

[6] Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 621--629

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 679--694

 []

[7] Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 745--753

 []

[8] Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 781--807

 []

[9] Overfull \hbox (1.28671pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 838--844 \TU/lmr/bx/n/12 Algorithm NAS Graphs \TU/lmr/m/n/12 Four step algorithm to cons truct all NAS graphs  []


Overfull \hbox (23.87996pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 849--853 []\TU/lmtt/m/n/12 (1) By repeated use of Algorithm ND Graphs list all non-isomo rphic  []


Overfull \hbox (0.39052pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 860--867 []\TU/lmtt/m/n/12 (3) For each graph $\OML/cmm/m/it/12 H[]$ \TU/lmtt/m/n/12 and  partition $\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 P[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/12 = \OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 f\OML/cmm/m /it/12 `[]; `[]; [] ; `[]\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 g$ \TU/lmtt/m/n/12 label its  []


Overfull \hbox (37.04715pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 860--867 \OML/cmm/m/it/12 t$ \TU/lmtt/m/n/12 vertices with $\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 f\OML/cmm/m /it/12 `[]; `[]; [] ; `[]\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 g$ \TU/lmtt/m/n/12 in all possible no n-label-isomorphic  []


Overfull \hbox (4.62152pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 860--867 \TU/lmtt/m/n/12 ways, ensuring that all parentless vertices have label $\OMS/cm sy/m/n/12 ^^U \OT1/cmr/m/n/12 2$\TU/lmtt/m/n/12 .   []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 889--907

 []

[10] Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 947--960

 []


Overfull \hbox (11.51994pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 987--992 []\TU/lmtt/m/n/12 (1) By repeated use of Algorithm ND Graphs, modified to gener ate  []


Overfull \hbox (35.51994pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 987--992 \TU/lmtt/m/n/12 connected ND graphs, list all non-isomorphic connected ND graph s  []


Overfull \hbox (0.39052pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 999--1006 []\TU/lmtt/m/n/12 (3) For each graph $\OML/cmm/m/it/12 H[]$ \TU/lmtt/m/n/12 and  partition $\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 P[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/12 = \OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 f\OML/cmm/m /it/12 `[]; `[]; [] ; `[]\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 g$ \TU/lmtt/m/n/12 label its  []


Overfull \hbox (37.04715pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 999--1006 \OML/cmm/m/it/12 t$ \TU/lmtt/m/n/12 vertices with $\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 f\OML/cmm/m /it/12 `[]; `[]; [] ; `[]\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 g$ \TU/lmtt/m/n/12 in all possible no n-label-isomorphic  []


Overfull \hbox (4.62152pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 999--1006 \TU/lmtt/m/n/12 ways, ensuring that all parentless vertices have label $\OMS/cm sy/m/n/12 ^^U \OT1/cmr/m/n/12 2$\TU/lmtt/m/n/12 .   []

[11] [12] [13] Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1298--1310

 []


Overfull \hbox (8.44823pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1339--1343 \TU/lmr/m/it/12 Proof.  \TU/lmr/m/n/12 As usual let $\OML/cmm/m/it/12 G$ \TU/lm r/m/n/12 have $\OML/cmm/m/it/12 t$ \TU/lmr/m/n/12 equivalence classes under $\O MS/cmsy/m/n/12 ^^Q$ \TU/lmr/m/n/12 given by $\OML/cmm/m/it/12 U[]; U[]; [] ; U[ ]$\TU/lmr/m/n/12 .   []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1363--1378

 []

[14] Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1391--1405

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1412--1416

 []

[15] [16] Overfull \hbox (4.90338pt too wide) detected at line 1677   [] [] []  []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1734--1740

 []

[17] [18] Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 1954  []


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 1954  []


Overfull \hbox (35.55821pt too wide) detected at line 1955
    []      []


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 1958  []


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 1958  []

[19] [20] [21] Overfull \vbox (32.2299pt too high) detected at line 2325  []


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 2332  []


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 2347  []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 2373--2376

 []

[22] Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 2447--2453

 []

[23] Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 2506--2508

 []

[24] Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 2575--2586

 []

[25] Overfull \hbox (3.24628pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2826--2855 [][] [] []   []


Overfull \hbox (3.24628pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2883--2910 [][] [] []   []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 2911--2914

 []

[26] [27] [28] [29] [30] [31] [32] (nasAFIN.aux) )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  3220 strings out of 411448  42979 string characters out of 5817462  1866698 words of memory out of 5000000  23455 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000  524572 words of font info for 91 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000  1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191  55i,12n,62p,205b,281s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

Output written on nasAFIN.pdf (32 pages).
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Please show your log file

Comment: looks ok here, but try with lualatex instead. If that fails too, show the log-file.

Comment: Thanks all.When I made the file just those 2 commands, it did work, but in my main file it still didn't:, here is the logfile for the run which didn't work:

Comment: posting an example that has no problem dos not help, edit to have a small but complete document that shows the problem

Comment: I fiddled around some more, and It seems to be working well now with lualatex.

Comment: what happens if you change the order of `\rput`  and `\psline' ?

Comment: This log file is for a 32 page document with at least 2914 lines.  How is that related to your example?